# Why does Chrome sometimes show a dialog window to enter credentials when the proxy is active?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, proxy

Proxi works. Password updates when necessary. However, occasionally and quite infrequently, a dialog appears for entering the username and password. Why does this occur?

```
function onAuthRequired(details, callback) {
  Promise.all([getStatusFromStorage, getUserFromStorage, getPasswordFromStorage()
  ]).then(async ([status, username, password]) => {
    if (status === 'connected' && details.isProxy) {
      const isPasswordExpired = Date.now() - password.fetchDate > password.expiresIn

      if (isPasswordExpired ) {
        const newPassword = await fetchPassword()
        await savePasswordToStorage(newPassword )
        callback({
          authCredentials: { username, password: newPassword  },
        });
      } else {
        callback({
          authCredentials: { username, password },
        });
      }
    } else {
      callback({})
    }
  })
}


chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  onAuthRequired,
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  ['asyncBlocking']
)
```

I expect the proxy to work continuously and stably